# Use AWS ELB as a service to point traffic to servers outside AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, shared-hosting

I have a shared hosting account on Go Daddy and have multiple servers where i have my code. What i need to do is use an ELB or an ALB instead of Route 53 to route traffic among multiple servers to manage load. Now i am not sure if one can use ELB or ALB a service to route traffic outside the aws environment. Can anybody help with this ??

Answer (score 2):

If you can interconnect the network hosting servers outside AWS with the VPC containing ALB then you can route traffic to both AWS internal and external servers. This functionality is to use ALB for an extended network AWS + on-premise/enterprise environment. The interconnect can be created either through VPN or Direct connect.

[Application Load Balancing via IP Address to AWS & On-Premises Resources](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-application-load-balancing-via-ip-address-to-aws-on-premises-resources/)

> In order to address these use cases, Application Load Balancers can
>   now route traffic directly to IP addresses. These addresses can be in
>   the same VPC as the ALB, a peer VPC in the same region, on an EC2
>   instance connected to a VPC by way of ClassicLink, or on on-premises
>   resources at the other end of a VPN connection or AWS Direct Connect
>   connection.

Comment: i did try to create a target group redirecting the traffic to the public ip of the shared servers but it does not allow me to create a vpc as it shows that the ip is outside the environment

Comment: It does not work for any public server, you need to first extend the AWS network with your server environment either using VPN or Direct Connect

Comment: Are you suggesting using a site to site vpn connection between the shared server and the elb?

Comment: Yes but VPN connection needs to be between site router and the aws VPN gateway